# How to reload a div for equal height child on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

I wrote a script to give equal height to child elements of wrapper. It is working fine on page load, but when I resize or change the orientation of my iPad, the height remains the same as it was during page load.

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
     $('.equal-height-wrapper').each(function () {
     var heightArray = [];
     var allbox = $(this).find(".equal-height-box");
     $(allbox).each(function () {
     heightArray.push($(this).height());
     });
     var maxBoxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heightArray);
     $(this).find('.equal-height-box').css('height', maxBoxHeight);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="equal-height-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="equal-height-box">

    </div>
    <div class="equal-height-box">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to update the height of the child elements when they change. As of now, I've added overflow hidden so that any text that overlaps gets hidden.

I tried placing this script on load resize, but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapped code in a named function so you can call it in various ways. I'd replace window `.load` with `$.ready`. Also added `orientationchange` event. Then you get something like:

```
function setEqualHeight() {
  $('.equal-height-wrapper').each(function() {
    var heightArray = [];
    var allbox = $(this).find(".equal-height-box");
    $(allbox).each(function() {
    $(this).height("");  // remove previously set heights
    heightArray.push($(this).height());
    });
    var maxBoxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heightArray);
    $(this).find('.equal-height-box').css('height', maxBoxHeight);
  });
}

$(function() {
  $(window).on('resize', setEqualHeight);
  $(window).on('orientationchange', setEqualHeight);
  setEqualHeight();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the important thing I missed: remove the heights set previously! They are inline styles, have more css specificity (importance) than styling from stylesheet or style tag, and so jquery will use them! Anyway css only solution is of course better... but edited my script anyway

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, if there's a lot of resizing going on and cpu load is a concern you may want to do some rate-limiting on calling setEqualHeight()

Answer (score 1):

Why not using only CSS ?
Something like this could work...

*(Updated to work with FIXED container height, and unknown container height)*

```
/* For fixed container HEIGHT */
.container-1 {
    display: block;
    width:150px;
    background-color:yellow;   
    height:200px;
}
.child-1 {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:100%;
}
/* FOR UNKNOWN CONTAINER HEIGHT */
.container-2 {
    display: table;
    width:150px;
    background-color:yellow;   
}
.child-2 {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bkG5A/740/

You could also, consider using **[CSS FLEX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Comment: yes..but here the container has height 200px. For me the height is not fixed...it could be anything

Comment: remove the height of the container and will still work. i've just added some extra CSS to expose clearly the behaviour (like that height , and the colors. ) I'll update the code, to keep the essential.

Comment: just checked the jsfiddle..the two red boxes are unqual height...I was trying to achive equal height for both red boxes

Comment: You are right. I updated again, to work on both situations, using only CSS.

Comment: hey, yes it works..but I have a doubt..what if the child element is not a direct child...I updated the html in my question. The script actually works even if the child is not a direct child..it's just that on resize..it needs to do the job again

Comment: In that case wouldn't work. Just for direct childs of the container.